A non-isomorphic bijective regular map
It seems a silly question but frankly I really don't know how to prove it. Fix a algebraically closed field $k$ with $\operatorname{char} (k) \ne 2$. Consider a regular map between two affine alegrbaic sets
\begin{align*}
 f : \mathcal{Z} (u(v- 1) - 1) & \longrightarrow \mathcal{Z} (y^2 - x^2(x + 1)) \\
 (u, v) & \longmapsto (u^2 - 1, u(u^2 - 1)).
\end{align*}
It is easy to show that $f$ is bijetive, and
\begin{align*}
 f^{-1} : \mathcal{Z} (y^2 - x^2(x + 1)) & \longrightarrow \mathcal{Z} (u(v- 1) - 1), \\[10pt]
 (x, y) & \longmapsto (u,v) = 
 \left\{\begin{matrix}
  (-1, 0), & (x, y) = (0, 0), \\
  \left( \frac{x}{y}, \frac{y}{x} + 1 \right), & (x, y) \ne (0, 0).
 \end{matrix}\right.
\end{align*}
How can I show that $f^{-1}$ is not a regular map? i.e. How can I show that there isn't any $f_1, f_2 \in k[x, y]$, such that
$$
(f_1, f_2)|_{\mathcal{Z} (y^2 - x^2(x + 1))} = f^{-1}?
$$
$x / y$ is not very polynomial-like, but as we all know, if we consider $\mathbb{F}_p$, every function $g: \mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p$ can be induced by some polynomial. So it is not really trivial for me to convince myself that $f^{-1}$ is not regular. The fact that $k$ is algebraically closed (at least, $|k| = \infty$) must be used.

ps: It is the Exercise 1.12 of Gortz and Wedhorn's book Algebraic Geometry I: Schemes.

Hello, I haven't looked too hard but it seems easy (not sure) to show that $f^* : k[x,y]/\langle y^2-x^2(x+1)\rangle \to k[u,v]/\langle u(v-1)-1 \rangle$ is not surjective.
